# Packages dependencies after sudo apt upgrade?

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, lubuntu

after `sudo apt upgrade` terminal says these lines belows are the packages that are not required anymore (auto-installed).

Do have I to `sudo apt autoremove` or some of these packages are used as dependencies for other applications? How to know about them? 
Lubuntu here.

```
 linux-headers-4.8.0-32 linux-headers-4.8.0-32-generic linux-headers-4.8.0-34
  linux-headers-4.8.0-34-generic linux-headers-4.8.0-37
  linux-headers-4.8.0-37-generic linux-headers-4.8.0-38
  linux-headers-4.8.0-38-generic linux-headers-4.8.0-39
  linux-headers-4.8.0-39-generic linux-image-4.8.0-32-generic
  linux-image-4.8.0-34-generic linux-image-4.8.0-37-generic
  linux-image-4.8.0-38-generic linux-image-4.8.0-39-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.8.0-32-generic linux-image-extra-4.8.0-34-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.8.0-37-generic linux-image-extra-4.8.0-38-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.8.0-39-generic
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo apt autoremove` will safely remove any obselete packages without damaging your system. The packages listed are those used to compile the Linux Kernel for your system.

Autoremove will delete old version to clear disk space on your system, but will also keep one old kernel version to revert to in case your system doesn't work with the most recent kernel version. It should be perfectly safe to use the command.

Comment: You beat me to the answer.  +1  =)

Comment: Fast fingers today!