# What to do in the situation of "installed some dependencies to build a package and the build still failed, now left with dependencies I didn't need"?

Tags: cleanup

What to do in the situation of "installed some dependencies to build a package and the build still failed, now left with dependencies I didn't need"?

This seems as if it could eventually cause bloat to the system.

I thought:

- always try installations/builds to a "sandbox" OS first, like virtual box Ubuntu or something
- organize main OS so that it's possible to do full clean installs of OS from time to time to clear all the junk

Anything else?

Comment: If you do a `sudo apt --simulate build-dep <packagename>` it will show you all the dependencies that got installed or should have been installed, so you can reverse it and use `sudo apt remove <listofdependencies>`.

Comment: @Terrance Even if I installed them manually?

Comment: @mavavilj It wouldn't hurt to try.

Comment: @mavavilj Depending on the app, you can also check with whoever the developer is and see if they have that list of dependencies for that specific app.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Packages dependencies after sudo apt upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/q/893353/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exactly is causing Debian to want to put packages up for "autoremove"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1220563/what-exactly-is-causing-debian-to-want-to-put-packages-up-for-autoremove)

Answer (score 2):

All dependencies pulled in by `apt-get` e.g. using the `build-dep` command are marked as "automatically installed". Once the package that needed them is removed, they can be removed by an "apt-get autoremove" command.

All dependencies you installed explicitly yourself are marked as "manually  installed". You need to explicitly remove them again to get rid of them. So indeed, you will need to take note of the packages you installed so you can clean up if your compilation effort ends up failing.

Something that may help you after the fact to identify packages installed on the date that you did the compilation. You can do so in the output of `grep install /var/log/dpkg.log` ([source and further info](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12578/list-packages-on-an-apt-based-system-by-installation-date)).

Comment: What if one installs using apt-get and dependencies succeed, but complete installation fails? Do they become available to autoremove?